# HTML: How to set up web page head and body with external file references

Tags: javascript, html, css, document-body, html-head

I am new to HTML and programming and hope someone can help me with this.

I have written the code for the first pages of my website and am now about to upload these to the server for a test.

Therefore I would like to know if the basic structure of my documents is correct and would like to get some comments on the following:

1. Should I add or change anything regarding my **document's head** ?
2. Do I include the **external style sheets** the right way and at the
   right position + is it correct to start the href with `"/"` here ?
   (I read CSS should be included before JS for
   better performance.)
3. Do I include the **external JS and jQuery references** the right way and
   at the right position ?
   (I read JS should be included at the end of the body for better performance.)

**Notes:** 
All PHP / HTML pages of my website are saved as separate files in the same folder. 
This folder also contains a sub folder `"includes"` where my stylesheet and functions file are saved.

**My HTML structure:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="author" content="John Doe" />
        <meta name="description" content="Created: 2015-06" />

        <base href="http://www.myURL.com/" target="_self" />

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- CSS -->        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" />
        <!-- CSS - Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
        <footer class="footer">         
            <!-- ... -->
        </footer>

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="includes/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Code review questions goes in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: <meta>, <base> and <link> tags are self closing in HTML and do not need the closing slash. Remove those.

Comment: the second stylesheet should start with http:// not //

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for this - I thought this way I would cover XHTML as well, no ?

Comment: @Braim: Thanks for this as well - it worked this way but will follow your suggestion.

Comment: You aren't serving XHTML and you can't do both at the same time. This is a well-worn fallacy of far too many people.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks - Ok, will apply then. It's all new to me and sometimes difficult to find the right instructions for such things so thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Looks good. Just a couple of minor things:

   - You should add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to ensure you don't get any MSIE compatibility mode issues.
   - You may add favicon definitions in the head.
2. Yes, stylesheets belong in the head. The href depends on where you are storing the css files.

   - If you want to include a stylesheet in the same folder as your HTML file, use `href="styles.css"`
   - If you want to include a stylesheet in another folder, e.g. [css] folder, use `href="css/styles.css"`
   - If you have HTML files in various folders and you don't want to rewrite your hrefs all the time for each HTML file, you can start the href with a slash to indicate search should start from the "root" of the server, e.g. `href="/css/styles.css"`
3. Move **ALL** your JS (including jQuery) to the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag. Unless there's a very strong reason why you need JS to run before the page starts displaying, you should not have JS in the head.

There are a lot of things to learn, but it can be very fun and rewarding. Hope you have an enjoyable programming experience ahead. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is really great and helps a lot ! :) My styles and functions are saved in a folder "includes" so I will use the href "includes..." for them. Regarding item 3, so I would just move the jQuery reference down to the body and above my JS reference ?

Comment: @keewee279 yes, move jQuery down to right above your other JS. Just another minor point: you don't need to specify type="text/javascript" for your scripts - save those bytes. In HTML5, the default is always JavaScript. And to date, there is no browser that uses another scripting language in place of JS.